# Java error when executing jar

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, minecraft

I have Ubuntu server 14 LTS installed on my machine and when I tried to launch Minecraft with Java (`openjdk-6-jre`) it fails. Same with the 7 version.

Here is the console output:

```
   root@server:~# java -jar /home/server/minecraft/forge.jar
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTar.getException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav a:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:43)
        at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Level
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.la unch(Launch.java:94)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
         ... 8 more
```

Comment: You are missing the jars for `org.apache.logging.log4j`

Comment: Thank you. How do I add the jars. Would reinstalling apache help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs to see how to set java `classpath`. It looks like it cannot find the `log4j.jar` file from the exception. Normally it would be something like below

`java -cp pathtoJar1:pathToJar2... -jar pathtoforg.jar`

Comment: Thank you. I looked up how to set the classpath but what do I set it to?

Answer (score 0):

http://keinett.com/forums/index.php?threads/shiginima-launcher-1-602-crash-with-forge-1-8-11-14-0-1281.1509/
says that

> that launcher does not support forge 1.8. you'll have to use the
>   official launcher.

They have same stacktrace :

```
Client> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Level
Client> at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:94)
Client> at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Client> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
Client> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
Client> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1.8 is referring to the version of minecraft not the version of java. Take a  look at forum link I posted, it is explained there.

Comment: Yes I'm running Minecraft 1.7.10 but I read the forum and I'll try the workaround tonigh